# How to re-enable NAT on Netgear CG3100?

Tags: nat, cable-modem

I just accidentally disabled NAT on my CG3100. Now I only have 4 public IPs for all the devices. I really need to re-enable NAT on my CG3100.

How do I re-enable NAT on a CG3100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When NAT is disabled on the CG3100 the IP of the cable modem [is set to **192.168.100.1**](http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=45078). Simply visit **192.168.100.1** in your browser and turn NAT back on.

*The default username is admin and the default password is password.*